# Subscheme of projective space in general position

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

Let $k$ be a field and let $\mathbb{P}^n(k)$ denote $n$-dimensional projective space over $k$. What is meant by a *general linear space* in $\mathbb{P}^n(k)$ of codimension $m$, in the language of schemes?

I believe *linear space* just means *closed subscheme*, but how does one encode the property of a closed subscheme being in "general position"?

My question is similar to [What is a generic hyperplane of a projective space over $\mathbb{C}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/250392/what-is-a-generic-hyperplane-of-a-projective-space-over-mathbbc?rq=1), but I am interested in a precise formulation in the language of schemes, not the geometric picture. I have read on Wikipedia that the notion of "generic point" is suppposed to formalize this, but I don't understand how.

[edit] Also is there any relation between being "in general position" and being a "generic hypersurface" (the latter in the sense described on page 123 of Eisenbud-Harris "GEOMETRY OF SCHEMES"?).

[edit2] i accidentally wrote "geometric point" instead of "generic point" before

Comment: The fuzziness in the related notions of "general" and "generic" is discussed in Harris's book (cf. comment below my answer), page 54.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The linear subspaces $L$ of codimension $m$ in $\mathbb P^n$ are parametrized by a Grassmanniannan $\mathbb G=\mathbb G(n-m,\mathbb P^n)$ of dimension $(n-m+1)\cdot m$.
Thus to  every  $g\in  \mathbb G$ there corresponds a  codimension  $m$ plane $L_g\subset \mathbb P^n$.
A generic codimension $m$ plane is then a codimension $m$ plane corresponding to  some fixed subset $S\subset \mathbb G$ with nonempty interior.
So there is a subtlety here: the subset $S$ can vary according to the problem at hand.

**An example**
Consider the lines  $L\subset \mathbb P^2$.
The corresponding grassmannian  $\mathbb G=\mathbb G(1,\mathbb P^2)$ is the dual  projective plane $\mathbb (\mathbb P^2)^* $ with coordinates $(a:b:c)$ and  to the point $g=(a:b:c)\in \mathbb G$ corresponds the line $L_g\subset \mathbb P^2$ of equation $ax+by+cz=0$.
Now what does it mean that the generic line in $\mathbb P^2$ does not go through the point $Q=(1:2:3)$?
It means that these lines correspond to  the *open* subset $S\subset \mathbb (\mathbb P^2)^*=\mathbb G$ given by the inequation  $a+2b+3c\neq 0$.
Of course the generic line does not go through $(1:-1:2)$ either and this means that they correspond to **another** open subset $S'\subset \mathbb (\mathbb P^2)^*=\mathbb G$, namely $a-b+2c\neq 0$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Maybe I should have included some context. I'm reading the proof of Proposition 15 [here](http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/mexico.pdf) (page 62 in the pdf numbering). Would you mind clarifying what does it mean, in scheme language, when Serre says: 'Soit L une sous-variete  lineaire de P_s(k) de dimension ...; *si L est choisie "en position generale"*'?

Comment: In your answer, are you saying that one can choose any line corresponding to a point of $S$?

Comment: Serre is using the following result, which is **exactly** in the framework of my answer: if  $X\subset \mathbb P^n$ is a subvariety of dimension $d$  and if $k< n-d$, then the subset $S\subset \mathbb G(k,\mathbb P^n)$ corresponding to  $k$-planes $L\subset \mathbb P^n $ disjoint from $X$ is open: it is the complement of an irreducible variety $\mathcal C_k(X)\subset \mathbb G(k,\mathbb P^n)$ of codimension $n-d-k\gt 0$ in $\mathbb G(k,\mathbb P^n)$. See Harris's [Algebraic Geometry](http://books.google.fr/books/about/Algebraic_Geometry.html?id=_XxZdhbtf1sC&redir_esc=y) , page 142.

Comment: I think what I'm missing is the significance of S being open in the Grassmannian.  Any way so if I understood you correctly, Serre means that $L \subset \mathbb{P}^s$ is chosen such that the corresponding point of the Grassmannian is contained in the open subscheme $S$ defined as you wrote?

Comment: Ah, the section on General Objects in HARRIS really cleared things up for me.  I guess the point is that S will also be automatically dense.